# Using Zend Framework Db Tables without MVC

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db, zend-db-table

I am trying to use the Zend Framework without using the MVC structure, specifically the `Db_Table` classes.

I have created a couple of classes representing my database tables, i.e.

```
class DBTables_Templates extends Zend_Db_Table_Abstract  
{  
    protected $_name = "templates";  
}
```

When I try to instantiate this class (it is included fine), I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Table_Exception' with message 'No adapter found for DBTables_Templates'

Does anyone know how I create and include the database adapter for the `Db_Table` classes to use?

Any pointers are greatly appreciated! I am using the latest version of ZF.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to create a Zend_Db_Adapter, which is the class you use to connect to the database.

```
$db = new Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql(array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

Or you can use the `factory()` method to make instantiation more configurable:

```
$db = Zend_Db::factory('Pdo_Mysql', array(
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'username' => 'webuser',
    'password' => 'xxxxxxxx',
    'dbname'   => 'test'
));
```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.html#zend.db.adapter.connecting

Then specify this adapter object to your table class.  There are at least three ways to do this:

- Set an application-wide default for all tables:

  ```
  Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter($db);
  ```
- Specify the adapter to the table constructor:

  ```
  $table = new MyTable( array('db'=>$db) );
  ```
- Store the adapter in the registry and specify it to the table or set it as default:

  ```
  Zend_Registry::set('my_db', $db); 
  $table = new MyTable( array('db'=>'my_db') );
  // alternatively:
  Zend_Db_Table_Abstract::setDefaultAdapter('my_db');
  ```

See http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.db.table.html#zend.db.table.constructing